# Downloading from FTP in Swift

Tags: swift, ftp

I am trying to connect to and existing FTP server and download the folders and the Files inside those folders. I am lost as to how to do this.

I have the below function created. It seems to connect to the FTP server but I do not know what to do next.

If I can get the directory list and store it into an array I feel I could move forward, But I am not sure how to retrieve the data from the FTP Server.

```
func openFTPConnection()
{
    var url: CFStringRef
    url = "ftp://gg" as NSString
    var requestURL: CFURLRef
    requestURL = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, url, nil);

    let ftpStream = CFReadStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, requestURL).takeRetainedValue()
    var state = CFReadStreamOpen(ftpStream)

    if state == 0
    {
        println("False")
    }
    else
    {
        println("True")
    }

    var numBytesRead = 0
    var bufSize = 4096
    var buf = [UInt8](count: bufSize, repeatedValue: 0)

    do
    {
        numBytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(ftpStream, &buf, bufSize)
    }
        while( numBytesRead > 0 );


    CFReadStreamClose(ftpStream)

}
```